# Include category ID in import csv

Tags: php, magento, csv

I am building a new mage site from old database. Right now, I am importing a category csv using a script I found online. It works fine but I noticed that the category IDs increment and not really using the category IDs they have on the old site which will be troublesome when importing the products. Please help even just enlightenment if this is feasible or any better approach. Thank you very much.
I tried adding:

```
$catID = $importData['cat_id']; and 
$cat->setID($catID); (it didnt work)
```

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
class ImpCat_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Category extends Mage_Eav_Model_Convert_Adapter_Entity
{
    protected $_categoryCache = array();
    protected $_stores;
    /**
     * Category display modes
     */
    protected $_displayModes = array('PRODUCTS', 'PAGE', 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE');

    public function parse()
    {
        $batchModel       = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
        $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
        $importIds        = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();
        foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
            $batchImportModel->load($importId);
            $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
            $this->saveRow($importData);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Save category (import)
     * @param array $importData
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     * @return bool
     */
    public function saveRow(array $importData)
    {
        if (empty($importData['store'])) {
            if (!is_null($this->getBatchParams('store'))) {
                $store = $this->getStoreById($this->getBatchParams('store'));
            } else {
                $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, required field "%s" not defined', 'store');
                Mage::throwException($message);
            }
        } else {
            $store = $this->getStoreByCode($importData['store']);
        }
        if ($store === false) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, store "%s" field not exists', $importData['store']);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        $rootId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
        if (!$rootId) {
            return array();
        }
        $rootPath = '1/' . $rootId;
        if (empty($this->_categoryCache[$store->getId()])) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStore($store)->addAttributeToSelect('name');
            $collection->getSelect()->where("path like '" . $rootPath . "/%'");
            foreach ($collection as $cat) {
                $pathArr  = explode('/', $cat->getPath());
                $namePath = '';
                for ($i = 2, $l = sizeof($pathArr); $i < $l; $i++) {
                    $name = $collection->getItemById($pathArr[$i])->getName();
                    $namePath .= (empty($namePath) ? '' : '/') . trim($name);
                }
                $cat->setNamePath($namePath);
            }
            $cache = array();
            foreach ($collection as $cat) {
                $cache[strtolower($cat->getNamePath())] = $cat;
                $cat->unsNamePath();
            }
            $this->_categoryCache[$store->getId()] = $cache;
        }
        $cache =& $this->_categoryCache[$store->getId()];
        $importData['categories'] = preg_replace('#\s*/\s*#', '/', trim($importData['categories']));
        if (!empty($cache[$importData['categories']])) {
            return true;
        }
        $path            = $rootPath;
        $namePath        = '';
        $i               = 1;
        $categories      = explode('/', $importData['categories']);
        /*$IsActive = $importData['IsActive'];*/
        $IsActive        = $importData['is_active'];
        $IsAnchor        = $importData['is_anchor'];
        $Description     = $importData['description'];
        $IncludeInMenu   = $importData['include_in_menu'];
        $MetaTitle       = $importData['meta_title'];
        $MetaKeywords    = $importData['meta_keywords'];
        $MetaDescription = $importData['meta_description'];
        $Image           = $importData['image'];
        $URlkey          = $importData['url_key'];
        foreach ($categories as $catName) {
            $namePath .= (empty($namePath) ? '' : '/') . strtolower($catName);
            if (empty($cache[$namePath])) {
                $dispMode = $this->_displayModes[2];
                $cat      = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($store->getId())->setPath($path)->setName($catName)->setIsActive($IsActive)->setIsAnchor($IsAnchor)->setDisplayMode($dispMode)->save();
                $cat      = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
                $cat->setIncludeInMenu($IncludeInMenu);
                $cat->setDescription($Description);
                $cat->setMetaTitle($MetaTitle) . $cat->setMetaKeywords($MetaKeywords);
                $cat->setMetaDescription($MetaDescription);
                $cat->save();
                $cat                      = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
                $data['meta_keywords']    = $MetaKeywords;
                $data['meta_title']       = $MetaTitle;
                $data['meta_keywords']    = $MetaKeywords;
                $data['meta_description'] = $MetaDescription;
                $data['url_key']          = $URlkey;
                $cat->addData($data);
                $cat->save();
                $cache[$namePath] = $cat;
            }
            $catId = $cache[$namePath]->getId();
            $path .= '/' . $catId;
            $i++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve store object by code
     *
     * @param string $store
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Store
     */
    public function getStoreByCode($store)
    {
        $this->_initStores();
        if (isset($this->_stores[$store])) {
            return $this->_stores[$store];
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Init stores
     *
     * @param none
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _initStores()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_stores)) {
            $this->_stores = Mage::app()->getStores(true, true);
            foreach ($this->_stores as $code => $store) {
                $this->_storesIdCode[$store->getId()] = $code;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample csv that I import

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Sample CSV to import</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>store</th>
    <th>categories</th>
    <th>cat_id</th>
    <th>is_active</th>
    <th>meta_title</th>
    <th>meta_keywords</th>
    <th>meta_description</th>
    <th>include_in_menu</th>
    <th>is_anchor</th>
    <th>description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>default</td>
    <td>/Supplies</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```